# Symfony: REST API аутентификация

Tags: rest, symfony

Необходимо прикрутить к имеющемуся веб-приложению возможность отправлять запросы в JSON, помимо имеющихся стандартных реквестов (обычные страницы). Как это лучше всего сделать, сохранив при этом обычную авторизацию и обычные запросы? Опыта в создании REST API приложений еще не было, поэтому не очень знаю в какую сторону нужно копать.

Comment: Попытайтесь понять о чем вы хотите спросить.

Comment: @WGPavell вам нужно принимать json в приложении симфони?

Comment: Да, и не только. Нужно еще авторизовать пользователя посредством JSON запроса.